# Sample android ros code

Tags: usb, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a sample code that uses ros to communicate with android through usb? Completely lost and needed something to follow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201150/sample-android-ros-code/) by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use USB tethering, and sample-app.

http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/Building%20The%20Example%20Applications%20using%20the%20Binary%20Distribution

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0